# Querying Facebook Open Graph API with wildcards?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Ok so basically I'd like to be able to query the Facebook Open Graph API with wildcards to build an autocomplete for movies/music/etc.

Something like this works properly:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=twilight&type=page

But partial matches don't work:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=twilig&type=page

Putting a % at the end seems to turn up more results, so I think I might be on the right track, but it's still not quite right:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=twilig%&type=page

I haven't been able to find any documentation on using wildcards. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use FQL and the `strpos` function, something like:

```
SELECT page_id,name 
FROM page 
WHERE strpos(lower(name),"incep") >=0 
AND page_id IN (
    SELECT page_id 
    FROM page_fan 
    WHERE uid=me() 
    AND type="MOVIE"
)
```

This would return (for me):

```
[
  {
    "page_id": 91290503700,
    "name": "Inception"
  }
]
```

As you can see I've used the lower method **AND** used small letters in my query to make sure that the query will match.

Comment: Ah, so that only seems to work for items the current user already has in their profile. Is there a way to query against ALL items? I tried this (which didn't work): SELECT page_id,name FROM page WHERE strpos(lower(name),"incep") >=0

Comment: @JarinUdom: No, from the [page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/) table...you need to query an indexable field which are `page_id` or `name`. Using `strpos` on the `name` field **won't** count but using something like `name = "Inception"` will work which would be the case you are facing (which is expected of course)